# use multiple jboss instances in one machine independently using jboss tools

Tags: eclipse, jboss, multiple-instances, jboss-tools

I want to run two jboss instances (version 4.2.3) in one machine independently from each other and control them using jboss tools in eclipse.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can start several instances of JBoss in the same machine configuring each instance with different port bindings (to avoid port conflicts between the JBoss instances). For that you can use the JBoss binding service, you can find the steps about how to configure it in the section ["Providing alternate ports for each instance of JBoss AS"](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine) of this JBoss web.

Once you've the two JBoss instances properly configured, you just have to add them in Eclipse individually (as you'd do with a single one).